# sqoop import from MS SQL Server fails unless password in connect string

Tags: sqoop

Detail:

Sqoop 1.4.6

Tried password file located in HDFS and Local FS.  Also tried declaring the password file as `--password-file file:///user/username/password.file`

```
sqoop import \
--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://servername;database=databasename' \
--username userxxx \
--password-file password.file \
--table 'sales' \
--fields-terminated-by '|' \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N'  \
--hive-import
```

When running a sqoop import I am getting authentication failures from sql server unless I put the username and password in the connection string.  If I try to use -P or --password-file the authentication fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`--password-file`**

As per [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server),

> **Secure way of supplying password to the database.** You should save the password in a file on the users home directory with 400 permissions and specify the path to that file using the --password-file argument, and is the preferred method of entering credentials. Sqoop will then read the password from the file and pass it to the MapReduce cluster using secure means with out exposing the password in the job configuration. The file containing the password can either be on the Local FS or HDFS.

Check file's permission and it should be in home directory.

Sqoop expects `--password-file` in HDFS, if you are using local FS add `file://`.

Example: `--password-file file:///user/dev/database.password`

**`-P` option**

It will read password from console. Using this you have to write password while command executes.

**`password`**

Simply add you password.

Comment: I have tried all of those as outlined in my post.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @ATS AFAIK these are the only ways. I tried these myself and all of them work.

Answer (score 0):

There is also one better way of doing it. Using the ***expect scripting***.

Create a script file say "script.sh" :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
      set password "<ur password desination or file>"
      spawn sqoop <args>  # define sqoop command here
      expect "*?Enter password:*" # As ask for password as while reading from database
      send -- "$password\r"
      expect sleep 15  # or you can use "set timeout -1" for infinite waiting time
      expect eof
EOF
done
```

In case you are facing error that spawn command does not exist etc. It means that expect is not installed.

For centos7

```
yum install expect -y
```

and run the file "script.sh"

If expect script fails to load

Try :

```
> /usr/bin/expect script.sh
```

Thanks